# How to Flatten spark dataframe Row to multiple Dataframe Rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Hi I have a spark data frame which prints like this (single row)

```
[abc,WrappedArray(11918,1233),WrappedArray(46734,1234),1487530800317]
```

So inside a row i have wrapped array, I want to flatten it and create a dataframe which has single value for each array for example above row should transform something like this

```
[abc,11918,46734,1487530800317]
[abc,1233,1234,1487530800317]
```

So i got dataframe with 2 Rows instead of 1, So each corresponding element from wrapped array should go in new row.

**Edit 1 after 1st answer:**
What if i have 3 arrays in my input

```
WrappedArray(46734,1234,[abc,WrappedArray(11918,1233),WrappedArray(46734,1234),WrappedArray(1,2),1487530800317]
```

my output should be

```
[abc,11918,46734,1,1487530800317]
[abc,1233,1234,2,1487530800317]
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the best solution, but this would work:

```
case class TestFormat(a: String, b: Seq[String], c: Seq[String], d: String)

val data = Seq(TestFormat("abc", Seq("11918","1233"), 
            Seq("46734","1234"), "1487530800317")).toDS

val zipThem: (Seq[String], Seq[String]) => Seq[(String, String)] = _.zip(_)

val udfZip = udf(zipThem)

data.select($"a", explode(udfZip($"b", $"c")) as "tmp", $"d")
    .select($"a", $"tmp._1" as "b", $"tmp._2" as "c", $"d")
    .show
```

The problem is that by default you cannot be sure that both Sequences are of equal length.

The probably better solution would be to reformat the whole data frame into a structure that models the data, e.g.

```
root
-- a
-- d
-- records
---- b
---- c
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have on follow up problem here what if i have 3 arrays [abc,WrappedArray(11918,1233),WrappedArray(46734,1234),WrappedArray(1,2),1487530800317]

Comment: if you are okay with the answer you can vote up instead of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering @swebbo, you answer helped me getting this done:

I did this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, udf}
import sqlContext.implicits._
val zipColumns = udf((x: Seq[Long], y: Seq[Long], z: Seq[Long]) => (x.zip(y).zip(z)) map {
  case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c)
})

val flattened = subDf.withColumn("columns", explode(zipColumns($"col3", $"col4", $"col5"))).select(
  $"col1", $"col2",
  $"columns._1".alias("col3"), $"columns._2".alias("col4"), $"columns._3".alias("col5"))
flattened.show
```

Hope that is understandable :)